# ZSH Alias with Multiple Commands giving "command not found"

Tags: command-line, alias, zsh

I am using this series of commands to build and run a docker container.
The commands work when combined with `&&` and give output like this:

```
> docker stop $(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=redoc1) && docker build -t redoc1 . && docker run  -p 8070:80 -d redoc1 
4127c16715e8
3995f290bcf3
60cacd2d669b
7e509bd0f443
69e186743360
1caad359f950
Sending build context to Docker daemon  113.7kB
Step 1/2 : FROM redocly/redoc:v2.0.0-rc.18
 ---> 262cf1bbd824
Step 2/2 : COPY config/docker/index.tpl.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8b03c1555c5
Successfully built a8b03c1555c5
Successfully tagged redoc1:latest
183bd1af2d61968e67c6b0eec27d24a5892851ddc15b41bc155b8335de83f0ac
```

I am using Z Shell, and normally set up aliases for such repetitive sets of commands. Successfully, until now.

I created the following in `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias redocly-local-deploy="docker stop $(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=redoc1) && docker build -t redoc1 . && docker run  -p 8070:80 -d redoc1"
```

It's the same exact command as the one above, which works directly in shell.

But when running the alias (after reloading zshrc), it fails after the 1st (or second?) command:

```
> redocly-local-deploy 
4127c16715e8
zsh: command not found: 3995f290bcf3
zsh: command not found: 60cacd2d669b
zsh: command not found: 7e509bd0f443
zsh: command not found: 69e186743360
zsh: command not found: 1caad359f950
```

It looks like the *output* of the first command is throwing it off. I tried adding `> /dev/null` to the first command but got the same result.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It may be because `$(docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=redoc1)` is evaluated when the alias is loaded (because of the outer double quotes) rather than when it is evaluated - if that's not what you intend, then use single quotes

Comment: @steeldriver thank you! That was it. If you post as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering my own question based on @steeldriver's comment.*

`$(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=redoc1)` is evaluated when the alias is loaded (because of the outer double quotes) rather than when it is run, which is what's causing the issue.

The simple solution is to replace the double quotes with single quotes.